# Texture wrapping mode in compute shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl

I apologize beforehand for not providing code or images, I am more or less looking for clarification on whether what I'm doing is well-defined and my issues stem from some other bug.

I have implemented a separated Gaussian blur for exponential variance shadow mapping in a compute shader, which runs without issues (as far as I can visually tell). I wanted to re-use that same shader to blur downsampled luminance images for a bloom effect. The issue I observed was that obvious garbage values got blurred into the image at positive x/y in the respective passes (bright colored streaks of varying length). To check whether there is actually garbage inside the texture (we have to use a compatibility profile due to some uses of legacy code in other parts of the application, which makes using an actual frame debugger very difficult) I implemented the same shader (minus some changes regarding kernel size) as a full-screen fragment shader pass, which does not exhibit the noise blurring.

My question relates to the texture sampling in compute shaders. I use a `sampler2D` and `texture(...)` to read the to-be-blurred values, the wrapping mode is set to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. Does this perhaps not work as I expect it to in compute shaders? I issued memory barriers after each blur pass with TEXTURE_FETCH (not before, as the downsampling happens in a fragment shader, which shouldn't be an incoherent access).

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` works in compute shaders too. The only thing that doesn't work is the automatic texture derivatives. It's hard to tell what your problem is without seeing any code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I'll try to post some code and images when I'm back at work tomorrow.